# Magento 2 installing failed

Tags: magento2, installation, localhost, xampp, windows10

Installing user configuration...
[ERROR] CredisException: Connection to Redis localhost:6379 failed after 2 failures.Last Error : (10061) No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have Redis enabled in Xampp.  [Follow these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55813947/4002133).  A quicker way is to run `redis-cli ping` you should receive a PONG.

If successful then you may be missing the configurations needed for magento to communicate to the redis server.

It is recommended in the [Magento 2 docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/redis/redis-pg-cache.html) to run the magento CLI commands as it has further checks in place.

An example command:
`bin/magento setup:config:set --cache-backend=redis --cache-backend-redis-server=127.0.0.1 --cache-backend-redis-db=0`

Typical Redis settings are: IP: 127.0.0.1 PORT: 6379

Remember if you are using redis for other caching or session storage, I would recommend using another Number for your redis DBs to separate them.

If you want to check that redis keys are being populated (after a page refresh or action) then run this sequence of commands:

1. redis-cli (enters you into redis)
2. SELECT 0 (Number is your database number chosen)
3. KEYS * (Will output values in Redis DB)

[image: redis-commands-magento]